# función recursiva funciona en una tabla pero no en un modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursión

La función trabaja de manera correcta en el listado, como pueden ver en la columna **Partes** le das clic a **Ver** y podrán ver el resultado de la función, el problema que tengo es al darle al botón **Eliminar** (ubicado al final de cada fila, columna **Acción**), esta me repite los hijos de los padres principales, pueden observar el resultado haciendo clic el botón **Eliminar**.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    listar();
});

var listar = function(){
    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        filter: false,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true, 
        autoWidth: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/g0us7',
            method: 'get',
            data: function (d) {
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                    return meta.row+1;
                }
            },
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return row[1];
            }},
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return row[2];
            }},
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return '<a href="#" title="Listado de Partes Afectadas" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover-partes" data-placement="bottom" data-content="'+ listado(row[15])+'">Ver</a>';
            }},
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return row[4];
            }},
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return row[3];
            }},
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return row[5];
            }},
            { "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return row[6] + ' / ' + segundosAtiempo(row[7]);
            }},
            { "render": function () {
                return '<button type="button" class="eliminar delete-modal btn btn-danger botonEliminar"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Eliminar</span></button>';
            }},
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        fnDrawCallback: function() {
            $('[data-toggle="popover-partes"]').popover();
        },
        initComplete: function (data) {
        }
    });
    eliminar("#table tbody",table);
};

var eliminar = function(tbody, table){
    $(tbody).on("click","button.eliminar", function(){
        if(table.row(this).child.isShown()){
            var data = table.row(this).data();
        }else{
            var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        }
        modal = eliminar_dialog(data);
        modal.open();
    });
}

function eliminar_dialog(data){

    let dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
        title: 'Eliminar',
        message: function(dialogRef){

            dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0].setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');

            var form = $('<form/>',{
                'id' : 'form_eliminar_item',
                'role'  : 'form',
                'class'  : 'form-horizontal'
            });
            let div;
            let label;
            let div_field;
            let field;

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<h3/>',{
                    'for' : '',
                    'class' : 'text-center col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : '¿Desea eliminar este item?'
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Areas: '
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'text'    : data[1]
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Equipos: '
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'text'    : data[2]
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Partes: '
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'html'    : listado(data[15])
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Tipos de Mantenimiento: '
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'text'    : data[4]
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Mecánico: '
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'text'    : data[3]
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Observación: '
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'text'    : data[5]
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Inicio - Fin'
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'text'    : data[6]
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            div = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
            });
                label = $('<label/>',{
                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                    'text'    : 'Duración: '
                });
                label.appendTo(div);
                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                });
                    field = $('<span/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-10',
                        'text'    : segundosAtiempo(data[7])
                    });
                    field.appendTo(div_field);
                div_field.appendTo(div);
            div.appendTo(form);

            return form;
        },
        //cssClass: 'login-dialog',
        buttons: 
        [{
            label: 'Cerrar',
            icon: 'fa fa-remove',
            action: function(dialogRef) {
                dialogRef.close();
            }
        }],
        onshow: function(dialogRef){
        },
        onshown: function(dialogRef){
            $('#form_eliminar_item:first *:input:first').focus();
        },
        onhidden: function(dialogRef){
        }
    });
    return dialog;
};

function listado(listado_partes){
    let menujson = { "menu": listado_partes};
    function ordenar(j) {
     menu = { menu: [] };
     for (n in j.menu) {
      insertar(j.menu[n], 0, menu.menu);
     }
     return menu;
    }
    function insertar(j, l, menu) {
     for (n in menu) {
      if (menu[n].id == j.id_padre) {
       if (menu[n].menu == undefined)
        menu[n].menu = [];
       return menu[n].menu.push(j);
      } else {
       if (menu[n].menu)
        if (insertar(j, l+1, menu[n].menu))
         return true;
      }
     }
     if (l)
      return false;
     menu.push(j);
    }
    menu = ordenar(menujson);
    html=select2(menu.menu);
    function select2(menu, l) {
     if ( l == undefined)
      l=0, html="", pf="";
     let sp="&nbsp;".repeat(l*6);
     let n1="";
     for (n in menu) {
      n1=n;
      html += "<span>"+sp+menu[n].nombre+"</span><br/>";
      if (menu[n].menu) {
       select2(menu[n].menu, l+1);
      };
     };
     return html;
    }
    return html;
}

function segundosAtiempo(seconds){
    let numdays = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    let numhours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
    let numminutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    let numseconds = ((seconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    let result = '';
    if(numdays > 0){
        if(numdays == 1){
            result += numdays + " día ";
        }else{
            result += numdays + " dias ";
        }
    }
    if(numhours >0){
        if(numhours == 1){
            result += numhours + " hora ";
        }else{
            result += numhours + " horas ";
        }
    }
    if(numminutes >0){
        if(numminutes == 1){
            result += numminutes + " minuto ";
        }else{
            result += numminutes + " minutos ";
        }
    }
    if(numseconds >0){
        if(numseconds == 1){
            result += numseconds + " segundo ";
        }else{
            result += numseconds + " segundos ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<table class="display nowrap" id="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Equipo (N° Activo - Nombre - Serial / Marca - Modelo)</th>
            <th>Partes</th>
            <th>Tipo de Mtto</th>
            <th>Mecánico (C.I. / Apellidos, Nombres)</th>
            <th>Observaciones</th>
            <th>Inicio - Fin / Duración</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Equipo (N° Activo - Nombre - Serial / Marca - Modelo)</th>
            <th>Partes</th>
            <th>Tipo de Mtto</th>
            <th>Mecánico (C.I. / Apellidos, Nombres)</th>
            <th>Observaciones</th>
            <th>Inicio - Fin / Duración</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Actualización 1:**

**Color Rojo**: Columna **partes** en la tabla y la columna **partes** reflejada en el **modal**.

**Color Azul**: subnivel o hijo que da la función **recursiva**.

[image: repetición de los subniveles o hijos]

Comment: Yo le doy a eliminar y no pasa nada

Comment: ¿@Lorthas Te muestra el **modal**?

Comment: @Lorthas actualice la pregunta y adjunte una imagen demostrando donde esta mi error o lo que no deberia de suceder.